# Writing non-bracketed list items to CSV cell

Tags: python, list, csv

So I have 3 lists and all 3 contain the same amount of items:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = [['list_value'], 'string_value', ['another_list_value', 'yet_another_list_value']]
```

However for list3, I want to write the string value and not the list to the CSV cell. For example:

This: `another_list_value, yet_another_list_value`
Instead of: `['another_list_value', 'yet_another_list_value']`

What's the best way to do that? I'm guessing a loop and an isinstance check?

Comment: Use `.join(', ')` to convert the list to a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join()` to create a comma-delimited string.

```
csvfile.writerow(i.join(', ') if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in list3)
```